# Embedded Jetty 11.0.x and Proxying Websockets

Tags: websocket, jetty

Trying to understand proxying Websockets using Embedded Jetty 11.0.x.   I can get one-way communication working by registering a WebSocketAdapter and on onWebSocketConnect creating a connection to the target server.  Then I can receive requests from the client and pass them along to the target server.

The issue I'm having is how to send requests back to the client?  On the webSocketAdapter call, i see the onWebSocketMessage(String) method, but there is no indication of *who* sent the message. (I'm surprised they dont pass the Session object along with the message...)

Is this the right approach?  I've seen the test code example which proxies using Frames, but that seems more complicated than it needs to be for a simple proxy that doesn't care about the content of the Frames...

Any help or links to examples would be appreciated..